dynamic number of fields in executemany call
I have a little python app that reads a large amount of data, and then attempts to insert it into a table.
To avoid having it all in memory, I utilize the executemany method, using a generator.
This program is very generic, and as such I do not know the number of fields in the table that I'm inserting into. However the number of fields in the list returned by the generator will be equal to the number of fields in the table.
This is the code that works for my first test:
writecur.executemany( f"""INSERT INTO {self.schema_name}.{self.table_name} 
                      ({','.join(fields)}) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", [rec for rec in batch])

The fields variable has a list of the fields I am inserting into, and the batch is the result of the generator that uses islice to create a list of tuples (same number of values in the tuple, as there are fields in fields.
In the example above, there are 8 values in each rec .
Now the last [outstanding] step is to have the number of "%s"'s be dynamically added to the f string rather than the hardcoded 8 of them.
What is a slick way to do that? (I use sqlalchemy and should stick with that at least)
Or.. is there an even better way to do this, maybe without using f strings...  I'm open to the best method..
Note that the table name is also dynamic.
Thanks!

Does this answer your question?

thanks.. i'll try that:  values_placeholder = ','.join(['%s'] * len(cols))
sql_update = (f"INSERT INTO {self.tbl} (col_names) VALUES ({values_placeholder})")

yeah.. that simple. I swore i tried that and it took the placeholders literally / messed up with the formating of strings.. but that was likely before I switched to the f string.  Thanks.. i can accept the answer if you want
